# Changing some XML tags names but leaving unchanged values between them

Tags: regex, xml, replace, find, notepad++

In one of my XML file I need to find and replace some opening tags names using regex and **Notepad++**. Also I need to leave unchanged every text between them.

Example:

```
<uri>http://domain-name.com/41874_01_home_big.jpg</image_big>
```

I need to change into:

```
<image_big>http://domain-name.com/41874_01_home_big.jpg</image_big>
```

For some reasons I can't just change *uri* tag, cause there are others closing tags like */image_small* in the document (opened with *uri* of course).

I tried to change it like:

```
<uri>.*?</image_big>
```

But I don't know with what I should replace it.
I tried with:

```
<image_big>\1</image_big>
```

but result is:

```
<image_big></image_big>
```

without any text inside.

I need your help. I'm not good with regex.

Answer (score 2):

Just put `.*?` inside a  capturing group.

```
<uri>(.*?)<\/image_big>
```

Then replace the match with `<image_big>\1</image_big>` or `<image_big>$1</image_big>`

Your regex `<uri>.*?</image_big>` matches correctly but in-order to fetch all the characters which are matched by `.*?` pattern, you must need to put that pattern inside a capturing group. So that we could back-reference it for later use.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wU4xK1/11)

Answer (score 2):

Find:`<uri>(.*?)</image_big>`

Replace:`<image_big>\1</image_big>` or `<image_big>$1</image_big>`

See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/19